# how to navigation in zend framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have created on module called **Soap**, Controller called **Index** and action called **soapClient**.

Now I want to create an anchor tag which can redirect me to localhost/zf2/soap/index/soapClient using Zend Framework.

I dont want to write href manually. how I can do it in **Zend Framework 2**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be the same as in ZF1. Inside your view:

```
echo $this->url(array(
        'module' => 'Soap',
        'controller' => 'Index',
        'action' => 'soapClient'
    ), 
    'default',
    true
);
```

---

Edit:

according to the ZF2 Manual, usage is:

```
url($name, $urlParams, $routeOptions, $reuseMatchedParams)
```

see http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#url-helper